# What causes division error in this CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda, hardware

I recently noticed an error when running our program on different hardware. I could track things down to the initial part of the kernel, where position within a grid ist calculated, using modulo (%) and division (/) operator.
This is the minimal working example that reproduces the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void div_issue( int blocks_x, int* block_offset)
{
    int blks_x = blocks_x;


    //number of block 2d
    int block_id_2d = block_offset[0]; 

    //x-coordinate of block in absolute grid
    int block_idx = block_id_2d % blks_x;

    //y-coordinate of block in absolute grid    
    int block_idy = (block_id_2d - block_idx) / blks_x;

    printf("%d mod %d = %d \n", block_id_2d, blks_x, block_idx);
    printf("%d / %d = %d \n", block_id_2d - block_idx, blks_x, block_idy);

}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dev_count;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&dev_count);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < dev_count; i++)
    {
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
        printf("using device %s :\n\n", prop.name);

        int block_offset_host[1];
        block_offset_host[0] = 753;
        int* block_offset_dev;
        cudaMalloc(&block_offset_dev, sizeof(int));
        cudaMemcpy(block_offset_dev, block_offset_host, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        div_issue <<<1, 1 >>>( 251 , block_offset_dev);

        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Result (on my machine having 2 GPUs):

```
using device GeForce GTX 980 Ti :
753 mod 251 = 0 
753 / 251 = 4 
using device GeForce GTX TITAN Black :
753 mod 251 = 0 
753 / 251 = 3
```

I am using CUDA 7.0, Visual Studio 2012, 9.18.13.5306 WHQL on Windows 8.

I have no other hint, that the 980Ti could be damaged hardware. 
Can somebody confirm the issue on their own hardware?

So far it seems it does not happen in debug mode. No additional parameter such as `-use_fast_math` `-prec-div=false` `-prec-sqrt=false` was used for compilation.

Comment: I could not reproduce this on a Titan X. Have you tried the CUDA 7.5 RC?

Comment: @Jez thanks for trying. No, we do not have 7.5 RC yet.

Comment: Could not reproduce on GTX 680 with CUDA 7 on Linux.

Comment: Works fine on K20m and CUDA 6.5

Comment: @Benthebear  I would suggest filing a bug with NVIDIA.

Comment: @njuffa thanks, I did file a bug. So far I have been pointed to the fact that I should compile with -sm_52. I always thought there was some sort of backwards compatibility, as I never encountered an issue like this. If I get a definitive answer I will post it here.

Comment: Compiling for the actual architecture of your GPU is always recommended, and if that fixes the issue, that is what you would want to do. However, JIT compilation from PTX generated for earlier architectures (e.g. sm_50, sm_35) should also work, and if it doesn't that should be treated as a bug.

Comment: I understood it exactely this way as well: Ideally you name the target architecture, but you should be fine using sm_20 or sm_30 for any future hardware as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing a bug report with Nvidia it was confirmed that this is a compiler bug they have known about already. It is supposed to be fixed in CUDA 7.5 (final, not RC).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with `cuda 7.5 rc` compiler (`cuda 7.5.7rc`, `linux ubuntu 14.04`, `titan X`), however it seems to be fixed for `cuda 7.5.18 (final release)`.